# How can I create a secure cookie? I tried every thing but still not work

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I can set a normal cookie, like only set name, value and expires. But I can't set it into secure cookie or httpOnly cookie or both.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
setcookie("TestCookie", "CookieValue", 0, null, null, true, true);
if(isset($_COOKIE["TestCookie"])){
    echo '$_COOKIE["TestCookie"] = '.$_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
    session_id($_COOKIE["TestCookie"]);
}
else
    echo "Sorry! Cookie TestCookie was not set.";
?>
```

I have searched in search engine. Try every way. Such as changing a setting in php.ini etc.

It showed no error but it still doesn't work. Please answer on my question.

Comment: How are you checking to see if this cookie is secure or not?

Comment: Really I don't know. I just set it as a secure cookie to protect a cookie value from hacker. I mean I protect the cookie from a one who is stealing HTTP header between server and client.

Comment: To protect anything between server and client, you should be using ssl (https) anyway, are you?

Comment: Yes, but I am testing the PHP script in HTTP because I use a self-signed certification. It is difficult to test PHP in browser because some browsers don't let me browse into localhost with HTTPS.

Comment: I've yet to come across a browser that didn't let you use https with localhost; just because most browsers warn about snake-oil signed certificates, very few will block you completely

Comment: You are right, now I can. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sixth argument of [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) ensures that the cookie will be only set for HTTPS requests. Set it to false, or be sure to connect via HTTPS.

Also, note that `setcookie` won't modify `$_COOKIE`, since cookies are loaded only once, before the script's execution.

If you need to get the value from the `$_COOKIE` variable, you should set it manually:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "CookieValue", 0, null, null, true, true);
$_COOKIE["TestCookie"] = "CookieValue";
```

You can also refresh the page, but that could create a redirection loop for people who have disabled cookies in their browsers:

```
<?php
setcookie("TestCookie", "CookieValue", 0, null, null, true, true);
if(isset($_COOKIE["TestCookie"])){
    echo '$_COOKIE["TestCookie"] = '.$_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
    session_id($_COOKIE["TestCookie"]);
}
else{
    header('Refresh: 0');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you please tell me how to print a cookie value from "$_COOKIE" when the cookie is already set. I always have to refresh the page once more to take a cookie value. Thank you again!

Comment: Of course, I've edited my answer with some solutions.